# filterModel not working in yii2 framework

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii2

I had installed the yii2 advanced template, but when I integrate an admin template, all was working except the  `filterModel` (when I press ENTER nothing happens), I think it's because the the style but how I can modify that. It's working just when I'm use "site.css" style of yii2.
Any suggestions?

Image of my table `filterModel`:
[image: image of my table filterModel]

this is the `GridView` Code :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        /*'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,*/
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'id' => 'table',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'layout'=>"{sorter}\n{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}",
        //'summary' => $count < 2 ? "" : "Showing {begin} - {end} of {totalCount} items",
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf'],

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'idArticle',
            'designationArticle',
            'prixArticle',
            'poidsArticle',
            //'idUniteArticle0.libelleUniteArticle',
            //'idFamilleArticle0.libelleFamilleArticle',
            [
                'attribute' => 'idUniteArticle',
                'value'=> 'idUniteArticle0.libelleUniteArticle',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'idFamilleArticle',
                'value'=> 'idFamilleArticle0.libelleFamilleArticle',
            ],
             'dateAjoutArticle',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
        'rowOptions' =>['ng-model'=>'art'],
    ]); ?>
```

**EDIT** (as requested in comments):
this is the `controllerAction`:

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Article;
use backend\models\ArticleSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\JsonParser;

/**
 * ArticleController implements the CRUD actions for Article model.
*/
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
                /*'index'  => ['get'],
                'view'   => ['get'],
                'create' => ['get', 'post'],
                'update' => ['get', 'put', 'post'],
                'delete' => ['post', 'delete'],*/
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all Article models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ArticleSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model=Article::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        // the search Model 
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'articles' =>$model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single Article model.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new Article model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Article();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->dateAjoutArticle= date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idArticle' => $model->idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $model->idFamilleArticle]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing Article model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idArticle' => $model->idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $model->idFamilleArticle]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing Article model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

public function getAllArts(){
    $model=Article::find()->all();
    echo json_decode($model);
}

/**
 * Finds the Article model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return Article the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    if (($model = Article::findOne(['idArticle' => $idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $idFamilleArticle])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

and here is the `SearchModel`:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\Article;

/**
* ArticleSearch represents the model behind the search form about        `backend\models\Article`.
*/
class ArticleSearch extends Article
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['idArticle'], 'integer'],
        [['designationArticle', 'dateAjoutArticle', 'idUniteArticle', 'idFamilleArticle'], 'safe'],
        [['prixArticle', 'poidsArticle'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}


/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Article::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'idArticle' => $this->idArticle,
        'prixArticle' => $this->prixArticle,
        'poidsArticle' => $this->poidsArticle,
        'idUniteArticle' => $this->idUniteArticle,
        'idFamilleArticle' => $this->idFamilleArticle,
        'dateAjoutArticle' => $this->dateAjoutArticle,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'designationArticle', $this->designationArticle]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

Comment: show your related controllerAction and the related search model

Comment: the controllerAction and the related search model are below thank you

Comment: Are you sure it depends on the stylesheet? Seems unlikely, but if so, try temporal removal of statements from your other stylesheet until it functions. I.e. possible table altering statements.

Comment: yes, because  when i use the default style Yii2 only , the Filter was working, but when I use my style, it not working

Comment: I have posted a first suggestion try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for actionIndex use only this

```
  public function actionIndex()
  {
      $searchModel = new ArticleSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

      return $this->render('index', [
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you scais Edge, this is the controllerAction

```
  <?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Article;
use backend\models\ArticleSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\JsonParser;

/**
 * ArticleController implements the CRUD actions for Article model.
*/
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
                /*'index'  => ['get'],
                'view'   => ['get'],
                'create' => ['get', 'post'],
                'update' => ['get', 'put', 'post'],
                'delete' => ['post', 'delete'],*/
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all Article models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ArticleSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model=Article::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        // the search Model 
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'articles' =>$model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single Article model.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new Article model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Article();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->dateAjoutArticle= date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idArticle' => $model->idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $model->idFamilleArticle]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing Article model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idArticle' => $model->idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $model->idFamilleArticle]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing Article model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    $this->findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

public function getAllArts(){
    $model=Article::find()->all();
    echo json_decode($model);
}

/**
 * Finds the Article model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $idArticle
 * @param integer $idFamilleArticle
 * @return Article the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($idArticle, $idFamilleArticle)
{
    if (($model = Article::findOne(['idArticle' => $idArticle, 'idFamilleArticle' => $idFamilleArticle])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

and that is the SearchModel

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\Article;

/**
* ArticleSearch represents the model behind the search form about        `backend\models\Article`.
*/
class ArticleSearch extends Article
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['idArticle'], 'integer'],
        [['designationArticle', 'dateAjoutArticle', 'idUniteArticle', 'idFamilleArticle'], 'safe'],
        [['prixArticle', 'poidsArticle'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}


/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Article::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'idArticle' => $this->idArticle,
        'prixArticle' => $this->prixArticle,
        'poidsArticle' => $this->poidsArticle,
        'idUniteArticle' => $this->idUniteArticle,
        'idFamilleArticle' => $this->idFamilleArticle,
        'dateAjoutArticle' => $this->dateAjoutArticle,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'designationArticle', $this->designationArticle]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

thank's for help

Comment: Two things 1) why you  have $model=Article::find()->all(); and 'articles' =>$model, in your indexAction . 2) don't permform the filter only  the field 'designationArticle', or all the field in grdiview?

Comment: I am sorry, but this tow things ' $model=Article::find()->all(); and 'articles' =>$model ' I added that to do the filter with AngularJS,but it not working too, I delete them but nothing was change. And the filter is for all field in gridView. thanks for your help

Comment: I  have asked if the filter don't work only for the field 'designationArticle', or don't work for any field ..